# What is the keyboard shortcut to move to the start of a line in iPython?

Tags: python, ipython

Whilst typing in iPython, pressing `CTRL+A` I get taken to the front of the line as expected.

Now, after entering a line and recalling it by pressing the `Up arrow` I want to jump back to the front again, so I press `CTRL+A`:

[image]

Why am I now stuck on the right side of the screen in an empty line?  If I press `Up arrow` then `Down arrow` here I get the original line and then I can `CTRL+A` to the front of it but I really have no idea why I was put on the right side in the first place.

I am on OS X 10.8.2

Comment: I don't have such an issue. Do you have the same problem in your terminal emulator?

Comment: What system/OS are you using? Do you have readline installed?

Comment: Ctrl+A is the shortcut. Your behaviour seems (or seemed, i read about it some time ago) to be an osx related bug, i tried your steps but all went smooth.

Comment: @gokcehan works fine in Terminal, and while editing a new line in iPython, only happens when navigating the history.

Comment: @DanielRoseman 10.8.2, I don't think I have readline.. is it required?

Comment: @JoranBeasley [Home] scrolls me to the top of the page.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo hmm, and here I thought it was some sort of split view "feature" of iPython this whole time...  Are you on OS X?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various well-known incompatibilities with the default line editing library included with OSX, called `libedit`. So much so that IPython should start with a warning: "libedit detected, readline will not be well-behaved".

That same warning should show you how to solve it: do `easy_install readline` to install the standard readline library, which is much better behaved.

(Note that for reasons I don't fully understand, you do apparently need to use easy_install, rather than pip as I usually recommend.)

Comment: Heh, I just noticed that warning now.  Thanks!

Comment: Although, now I have to figure out how to make it work in a virtualenv.

Comment: Just run the same command from within your activated virtualenv.

Comment: I had to disable `vi` mode in `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` for option `TerminalInteractiveShell.editing_mode`. Now the typical jumping shortcut works for me.